# Plotting FFT diagram in Python

Tags: python, scipy, fft

In SciPy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html) there is a part that I do not understand.
What does this mean ?

plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N/2]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code sample you plot the FFT of the signal. I guess what you're asking is why are we plotting only half of it? Frequencies pasts the Nyquist frequency (half of the spectrum) are symmetric and redundant. [Here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/why-is-the-fft-mirrored) is a nice answer that covers it in details.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm asking specifically what does
 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N/2]) mean ? I understand it is an array. I understand we take only half of it. But where does this definition come from ? I mean whole formula 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N/2]).

Comment: You take absolute value to get the amount of frequency present in the original function (the signal is complex after all). Half of it, because it's mirrored. 2.0 / N is a convenient scaling. There's no definition that says "here's how you have to plot it", it all depends on what you want to achieve. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yes a bit. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt. The posts below can help!

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59434/should-you-scale-the-fft-bins-by-1-n-where-n-is-the-number-of-points-in-a-tr

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63001/why-should-i-scale-the-fft-using-1-n

It seems Scipy and Matlab deal with DFT/FFT in the same way. The first post seems to be more direct, and the scaling rises from the definition of the DFT being used.

The scaling factor is in fact `1/N` and the `2` in the Scipy tutorial is just because half of the array `yf` was already sliced `2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2])`.